ggplot - making an internal pipeline within ggplot from object passed from previous pipeline
I am trying this very simple code:
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Bla = cyl+mpg) %>% 
  ggplot(. %>% 
           filter(am == 1), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

It doesn't work and gives out an error You've supplied a <fseq> object. However, the following works:
ggplot(mtcars %>% 
         mutate(Bla = cyl+mpg) %>% 
         filter(am == 1), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
  geom_point()

Therefore, it seems that it's not possible to pass the dot . argument to ggplot and then follow it along with a pipeline.
I swear that I used to be able to do this, therefore my questions are:

Was this changed at some point in ggplot and am I just doing the old thing; or was this never possible and I am doing it completely wrong?
If this was indeed changed, then what is now the preferred and suggested ways to pass these dot arguments?


Functions (and functional sequences) are allowed as the data argument for layers (like geoms and stats), not sure if they were ever allowed as the argument to ggplot itself. E.g. mtcars %>% mutate(Bla = cyl+mpg) %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point(data = . %>% filter(am == 1))

There are a few issues here.
First, the magrittr package allows you to create anonymous function by starting a pipe with a . So if you have
. <- 5
f <- . %>% `+`(2)

Note that f will be a function, it will not be 5+2 desipite the fact that . is defined to be 5. However, you can call it like a function with f(10). So if you start chains with a single period, you will have that problem. You can get around this issue with filter(., am == 1) rather than . %>% filter(am==1). See this question where that behavior is desirable.
The second issue is that the magrittr pipe always passes the value to the first parameter of the function unless you have a single . in one of the parameter slots. It has to be . alone, it can't be a function of . or the value will also be passed in the first parameter as well. So these are equivalent
x %>% foo(5, "apple")      foo(x, 5, "apple")
x %>% foo(5, .)            foo(5, x)
x %>% foo(10 + .)          foo(x, 10+x)
x %>% foo(bar(.))          foo(x, bar(x))

So since you have a function of . passed in, the pipe is still passing the entire dataset to the first parameter as well, one way to get around that is to wrap your code in braces. For example
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Bla = cyl+mpg) %>% 
  {
    ggplot(filter(., am == 1), aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) +
    geom_point()
  }

When you use braces ({}), no attempt is made to automatically fill the first parameter. This documented in the magrittr readme
